# Can I resize the camera window?

Tags: camera, resolution

I've been googling and trying to find an answer to my question, and I've tried the common answers I've found, but my problem persists so I thought I'd ask. 
Can I make the camera window (where the red arrows are) larger? It would be nice to actually see something through that tiny window.

I've tried to resize the resolution in that red box but without luck, and the Lock to Camera View isn't doing much either.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uncheck *Lock Camera to View* and then zoom in.
Then you can enable the lock again.
No need to change your camera resolution.

The camera lock works like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!