# In camera view (Num 0) I cannot find the viewfinder rectangle

Tags: camera

When I enter Camera View by pressing Num 0 I cannot find the viewfinder rectangle with outsides grayed out. When I set the camera to a certain view and then render, the rendering result is a bit zoomed out compared to the camera view. I have attached screenshots of my blender interface and the interface of the view tutorial. Please tell me how to get that viewfinder rectangle in the youtube sample.

[image: This is my blender screenshot]

[image: That fresh image in the viewfinder and the grayed outsides are what I have seen in every tutorial I watched and is missing in my Camera Prespective]

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure you're not just zoomed in too much? Toggle camera lock on/off and zoom out a bit. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159882/