# How to reopen camera border

Tags: camera

still fairy new to blender was wondering how do I reopen the grey border when viewing from camera view ?

really struggling here

The 1st image is from a newly on blender file, while 2nd the is the file i'm working on, both are viewing from camera view(numpad 0)

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure you're not just zoomed in too much? Toggle camera lock on/off and zoom out a bit. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159882/78972

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply. yes apparently that is the cause of the problem. toggle off camera lock/off and zoom out work.